# How use phly-expressive-oauth2clientauthentication module for zend-expressive

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, mezzio

Hy,

I would like to use this module (https://github.com/phly/phly-expressive-oauth2clientauthentication)in my expressive application.

I read this documentation [https://phly.github.io/phly-expressive-oauth2clientauthentication](https://phly.github.io/phly-expressive-oauth2clientauthentication/)

here is what I did :

in my config/autoload folder i add a oauth2clientauthentication.global.php with this array :

```
'oauth2clientauthentication' => [
    'routes' => [
        'production' => '/(:provider)(/oauth2callback)',
    ],
],
```

in my pipeline.php file i add

```
use Phly\Expressive\OAuth2ClientAuthentication\OAuth2CallbackMiddleware;

$app->pipe('/auth', OAuth2CallbackMiddleware::class);
```

in my ConfigProvider.php file i add a route with this config (I use slim router with https://github.com/acelaya/expressive-slim-router:

```
[
    'name' => 'admin',
    'path' => '/admin',
    'allowed_methods' => ['GET'],
    'middleware' => [
        SessionMiddleware::class,
        AuthenticationMiddleware::class,
        Action\AdminAction::class,
    ],
```

When i tried this url : 'http://blog/admin', i get my unauthenticated page with github button. But when i click on the button the url is : 'http://blog/auth/github?redirect=http://blog/admin' and get an error :

```
Unable to resolve service "Zend\Expressive\Delegate\NotFoundDelegate"
```

I do not understand where is the problem, anyone have an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you upgraded your Expressive installation without going through the [migration guide](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/reference/migration/to-v2/).

Check your `config/autoload/dependencies.global.php`. It should contain something like this:

```
use Zend\Expressive\Container\NotFoundDelegateFactory;
use Zend\Expressive\Delegate\NotFoundDelegate;

return [
    'dependencies' => [
        'aliases' => [
            'Zend\Expressive\Delegate\DefaultDelegate' => NotFoundDelegate::class,
        ],

        'factories' => [
            NotFoundDelegate::class => NotFoundDelegateFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```